# Html.DropDownListFor & Html.CheckBoxFor doesn't reflect on system

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model that looks like:

```
public class schoolModel
{
    public SelectList Categories;
    public school Entity;


}
```

where school looks like:

```
public class school 
{

int? CategoryId{get;set;} // foreingKey
bool IncludeAttached{get;set;}

}
```

I initialize schoolModel as follows:

```
var model = new schoolModel();
            model.Entity = schoolServiceAgent.Output.Entities.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Id == id);
            model.Categories = new SelectList(new GenderServiceAgent().GetCategoriesByAlias(null, true), "Id", "Alias", model.Entity.CategoryId);
```

and I use them like

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Entity.CategoryId, new SelectList(Model.Categories, "Value", "Text"), Model.Entity.CategoryId)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Entity.IncludeAttached.Value, new { @class = "form-control placeholder-no-fix", name = "IncludeAttached", @checked = "checked" })
```

but at the edit post the FormCollection has no value to     CategoryId , and    IncludeAttached

I try to get them using

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
{
    var categoryid = int.Parse(collection["CategoryId"]); 
    var result = selectedschool.inMediaArabicApp = bool.Parse(collection["IncludeAttached"]);

}
```

the above raise null exception , any idea how to solve that? the form surrounding the edit looks like

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Schools", FormMethod.Post,
                             new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML `form` code?

Comment: If you are using `POST` then you need to add an annotation on the controller action `[HttpPost]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using FormCollection why don't you use the .Net [Model binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx) capability?

Use `[HttpPost]` since you are posting from the form.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(School model)
{
   var categoryid = model.CategoryId; 
   var result = model.IncludeAttached;

}
```

Also, c# conventions are to use [Pascal Casing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for class names and variables.

Comment: Do you have Fiddler installed? Can you tell what your form is sending back to the server?